# Rails has_many but unique on associated model's column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

and a Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

The Product table has a column named `product_id` which is alpha-numeric and I want that a user can have many products but should be unique on `product_id`. I can add an index on `product_id` to be `unique` but that would mean another user can't have a similar product.

**To simplify the problem, there should be a unique entry per** `user_id` **and** `product_id`**.**

Is there any conventional method to achieve the same in Rails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation for validations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

You can use scoped uniqueness.

```
validates :product_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this with a validation of uniqueness of product_id with a scope of the User.

```
validates :product_id,
            uniqueness: {
              scope: :user_id, message: 'No duplicate products are allowed.'
            }
```